# how to put four buttons in all four corners of the frame in tkinter python gui

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Hey i am new to tkinter gui please help i want to add four buttons , one on each corner and this is what i tried please hjelp

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
labelsub2i = Label(root, bg="red")
labelsub2i.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.7, relx=0.1, rely=0.15)
#BUTTONS FOR OPTIONS
button1 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Aasdddddddddddddddddd").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
button2 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Bsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasad").grid(row=1,column=6,sticky=E)
button3 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Cdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqsdaa").grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)
button4 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Dadsssssssssssssssssssss").grid(row=3,column=6,sticky=E)
root.mainloop()
```

[so This is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arCYO.png)

[wanted to add buttons on those corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4xti.png)

[P.s.- thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJJA.png)

Comment: It's hard to give good advice without more details, there are a couple ways to do what you want. Will there be other widgets in the middle? Is it OK of the objects overlap if the user makes the window real small?

Comment: Replace `Button(labelsub2i, ...` with `Button(root` and `root.grid_columconfigure(2, weight=1)`, `root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)`. Read up on [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, you can use `place(...)` instead of `grid(...)`:

```
button1 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Aasdddddddddddddddddd")
button1.place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor='nw')

button2 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Bsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasad")
button2.place(relx=1.0, rely=0, anchor='ne')

button3 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Cdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqsdaa")
button3.place(relx=0, rely=1.0, anchor='sw')

button4 = Button(labelsub2i, text="Dadsssssssssssssssssssss")
button4.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='se')
```